# how to define the correspondence between two fields of an object

Tags: typescript

Here are the two basic type definitions:

```js
type AudioMeta = {
  rate: number;
  codec: string;
  duration: number;
};

type VideoMeta = {
  width: number;
  height: number;
  codec: string;
  duration: number;
};
```

Then I want to make a MediaData type:

```js
type MediaData = {
  type: 'audio';
  meta: AudioMeta;
} | {
  type: 'video';
  meta: VideoMeta
}
```

Usually, writing like this solves my problem.

But in some cases，for example, when defining a database field in typeorm, I cannot use the `|` symbol, I need a format definition like below：

```js
type MediaData = {
  type: 'audio' | 'video';
  meta: AudioMeta | VideoMeta;
}
```

But I know this is imprecise.

So my question is how to define `MediaData` more rigorously without using the `|` symbol method like I used before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  type AudioType = {
    aaa: number;
  };
  type VideoType = {
    bbbb: string;
  };

  type TypeMapType = {
    audio: AudioType;
    video: VideoType;
  };
  type FieldConstraints<T extends object> = {
    [K in keyof T]: {
      type: K;
      meta: T[K];
    };
  }[keyof T];


  type MediaType = FieldConstraints<TypeMapType>;

  let media: MediaType = {
    type: "audio",
    meta: {
      aaa: 1
    }
  };
```